# How to check if Word document content has been changed

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm looking forward for method to check if document has been changed.

1. Property `Activedocument.Saved` is not enough, because if you change sth and undo this, document hasn't been changed but `.Saved` will change.
2. Checksum of document text will be not enough, because not including change in formatting (bold, italic etc.).
3. Date/time and file size will be not enough (beacuse save command can change its even without change in document).
4. build-in in MS Word compare - I cant use this, beacuse first at all im working on subdocuments (one main document contain several subdocuments and I want to know which subdocument has been changed) and I don't want to create copy of subcdocuments, or create new document object to compare.

I invented that I will make checksum from `.WordOpenXML`.

On open main document I calculate checksum

```
For each sd in Activedocument.SubDocuments
    'calculate and remember checksum of subDocument
    ...
Next sd
```

On close main document

```
For each sd in Activedocument.SubDocuments
    'calculate and compare with previous checksum of subDocument
    ...
Next sd
```

But every check of `.WordOpenXML` return different value. It looks like WordOpenXML value is generated on each call.

Is it way to avoid this?

`Debug.Print Selection.WordOpenXML=Selection.WordOpenXML`

Resume `False` :-)

Or maybe you have other method to check if document has been changed?

Comment: You could use the subdocument 'Locked' property to prevent changes.

Comment: Thanks. But, lock subdocument isnt't good solution for me. I want change subdocuments. And I want know which subdocuments has been changed, because editing (or not) is separated part of workflow. In next step there are some process on changed documents. Only on those changed!

Comment: Evidently, you're trying to use Word's Master Document 'feature', which is catastrophically unreliable. See: https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/WhyMasterDocsCorrupt.htm. As that article observes: *A master document has only two possible states: Corrupt, or just about to be corrupt*.

Comment: I think (4) is your only option.